# How to use dtype inside a for loop while traversing a dataframe column-wise ? So that I can traverse each row of a particular dtype column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dtype

For example, I have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
| Name      | color     | id    | weight    |       
|-------    |--------   |----   |--------   |
| john      | blue      | 67    | 70        |       
| clara     | yellow    | -     | 67        |       
| diana     | red       | 89    | 56        |
```

Here the numeric columns like "id" and "weight" should have all numeric values, unlike the second value of "id" which is a '-'.

If I do `df.dtypes`, it returns:

```
| name      | object            
| color     | object    
| id        | object    
| weight    | float
```

**How can I traverse through the dataframe column-wise, then check if the type of column is an object, then if it an object, then check if it is becoming an object because of the typo '-' like id- if yes then raise a flag **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip up the column name and the dtypes to make a tuple:

```
for col_name, col_type in zip(df.columns, df.dtypes):
    if col_type == "object":
        # do whatever here
        pass
```

Comment: thanks , this structure enables me to do my work